# Meteor Observer Reuse: Will changing my publication return query to not use this.userId make my observer more reusable?

Tags: meteor, meteor-publications

I have a publication that returns a cursor that looks like this:

```
// Publication RETURNS THIS QUERY

Notepads.find({_id: notepadId, $or: [{userId: this.userId}, {'collaborators.userId': this.userId}], archived: false})
```

As you can see the query is unique to the user since it includes `this.userId`

I use `this.userId` in the publication as a form of security. You will only get back data if you are associated with that particular notepad.

In my app, multiple people can collaborate on a single notepad. So to make the observer more reusable will this adjustment help my app?

```
// Optimized publication

notepad = Notepads.findOne({_id: notepadId, $or: [{userId: @userId}, {'collaborators.userId': @userId}], archived: false})

if notepad?
  // Optimized publication RETURNS THIS QUERY 
  return Notepads.find({_id: notepad._id, archived: false})
else
  return
```

I think this is what observer reuse means. That the publication returns the exact same query for any user that subscribes to it. So is this correct, is this optimization worth the change?

Answer (score 0):

[Quoting from kadira.io on How Observers are Handled in Meteor:](https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-performance-101/content/improve-cpu-and-network-usage)

> In order to create identical observers, you need to create cursors
>   with:
>
> - the same collection
> - the same selector (query)
> - the same set of options (including sort, limit, etc.)

In your example the selector is not the same for different users.

Selectors are [Object Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals) and are evaluated before being passed into the .find call.  This means that `{_id: notepad._id, archived: false}` becomes

- `{_id: 'myNotebookID', archived: false}`, or
- `{_id: 'anotherNotebookId', archived: false}`.

As you can see, these are different selectors after you resolve `notepad._id`, and this happens before being passed to .find().

If your first db query had returned the same notepad because your second user was a collaborator on the first user's notebook, you would end up with the same selector, and a single cursor / observable. However for most apps this is not likely to be common enough to optimise for, especially as (as @Khang points out) you are going to lose reactivity.

So, it's not the same query, it's not going to reuse the observer, and is not worth the change.

Comment: hi. I am confused. Can you took another look at the optimized query I made. I did exactly like you said. If first find the notepad, then I return the cursor `return Notepads.find({_id: notepad._id, archived: false})` This is the change I made

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer! This is good stuff. But I do want to clarify one point. If many users are collaborating on a single notepad (same notepad._id), wouldn't this change help then? As far as reactivity, the code is setup such that the user will only subscribe once they are a collaborator. And if they are removed as collaborator, while they are on the notepad, it would still sync the notepad, and on the client I can watch the notepad and stop subscription if they are no longer collab. So with these cases in mind, is it now worth the change?

Comment: I guess is it worth the optimization if say typical notepad collaboration is between 5 users? 10 users? 40 users? I guess I would rather not do the optimization if it barely makes any difference and I loose reactivity

Comment: [Don't guess, and don't optimize - until you know you must!)](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)

Answer (score 0):

There are problem with your optimized version that is it is **not reactive**. Because you use `Notepads.findOne` as a security check to make sure user have access to the document.

Inside publication `.findOne` is not reactive, say at the time the publication is executed user have no access to the document so nothing is sent to client, then user is added as an collaborator but that makes no change because the publication will re re-run.